# IntelliJ can't work with Git when using built-in SSH executable

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

Our team just migrated from Eclipse to IntelliJ, and for just 1 guy (out of 25) Git isn't working (fatal: Not a git repository etc.)

Everything still works from cygwin Command line or SmartGit, it's just the IntelliJ integration that fails.

we did try to change the git.exe to be either cygwin's or SmartGit's but that doesn't make any change.

Comment: This is pretty vague. What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Comment: @Kenster - I'm aware of that. I'm looking for general things to look at - things to test (what's the main difference between IJ's ssh and native ssh for example.)

Comment: You could always stop using windows. Try running ubuntu in vagrant/virtualbox with intellij and git installed in it, it'll save you a lot of trouble and you can give everyone a copy of an identical dev environment.

Comment: @EngineerDollery it's ridiculous to change your OS just because GIT doesn't work properly. If you're more used to things on Windows, it'll just slow you down; even though GIT is supposed to work already.

Comment: Given how easy it really is to run up a VM using vagrant it's hardly ridiculous. Especially as the OP is already using cygwin so the learning curve is low.